# Search ALL files with ack

Tags: ack

How can I search **all** files (including binary) in the current directory with `ack` v2?

I want to do the same as doing `ack 'foo' **`, but just with a flag, so it works if I want to search all files in a specific directory without appending `**`.

---

Difference between `ack 'foo'` and `ack 'foo' **`:

```
$ mkdir test && cd test
$ printf '\x00\x01foo1\x00' > test1
$ printf 'foo2' > test2
$ ack 'foo'
test2
1:foo2
$ ack 'foo' **
test1
1:foo1

test2
1:foo2
```

Comment: Why do you want to use ack for this instead of grep?

Comment: @AndyLester I just thought that `ack` is always better than `grep`. I was wrong :).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, Ack searches for a pattern in all non-binary files below the
current directory.

I believe older Ack versions would search through binary files when you passed
them the `--binary` flag. This flag has been removed though. You may be able to
use grep instead.

```
grep -ar 'foo' .
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with symlinks. It has to do with binary files!

Comment: @Tyilo: I have modified my answer.

Answer (score 15):

When you pass no file name to ack, it operates on a built-in default set of files that excludes unrecognized binary files. If you do pass file names, it searches in all the files you pass. This explains the difference between `ack foo` and `ack foo **`.

### ack 1

In ack 1.x, use the flag `-a` to tell ack not to skip files whose type it doesn't recognize.

You can make an alias if you want that flag more often than not: add the line `alias ack='ack -a'` in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc`. If you set up this alias and want to call `ack` without the option, call `\ack` (the backslash disables alias expansion). Scripts are not affected by the alias, only interactive shells.

Alternatively, you can add the `-a` option to your `~/.ackrc`.

Matches in binary files will be listed as “Binary file test1 matches”. There is no way to disable this behavior without modifying Ack itself (at least adding a plugin).

### ack 2

In ack 2.0, the `-a` option has been removed. What you can do instead is to define a type that matches all files, and use the `-k` option to make ack include all files of that type. Note that file types are processed in an unpredictable order, to this will cause a random set of binary types to be processed as ordinary instead of as the usual type.

```
ack --type-set='all:match:.*' -k foo
```

This way the matches are printed even for files that would otherwise look binary. As above, you can add these options to an alias or to your `.ackrc`.

Comment: That's pretty sneaky, @Gilles.

Comment: @AndyLester, why was the -a option removed? The "This is because" in the return doesn't actually explain why I can't search unrecognized file types anymore.

Comment: Because 1.x's -a behavior, to search all unrecognized text files, is now the default in 2.0.

Comment: Weird, I have a minified js file that even that special match-all-types type-set can't find...

Comment: I'm here because of that: a text inside a minified js file, that is not parsed by ack. I thought the answer would be like "add -a"... I'm dissapointed.